# ionic 2 and onesignal, how to save playerId to local storage

Tags: android, ionic2, storage

I am using one signal in `ionic2` to do push notification, I have tested the plugin and it's working fine, but i want to go a step further by sending notification from my app server. Hence I need player ID, I followed the docs on the internet and I was able to show the playerId  as alert, but I want to store it my local storage. that is the challenge

below is my code

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      window["plugins"].OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(ids.userId));

        this.storage.set('playersID',  ids.userId);

    });

      // OneSignal Code start:
      // Enable to debug issues:
      // window["plugins"].OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});
      this._OneSignal.startInit("568ed291-8d30-441f-b7be-d0d99aaca596", '342271570971');

      this._OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this._OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
      this._OneSignal.setSubscription(true);

      this._OneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
        // handle received here how you wish.
      });
      this._OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
        // handle opened here how you wish.
      });
      this._OneSignal.endInit();    




    })    



    }
  }
```

I even tried using below code to no avail

```
    window["plugins"].OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(ids));

       window.localStorage.setItem('playerID',  ids.userId);

  });
```

I also comment out the alert, same story

Answer (score 0):

You need to be saving it *after the init*. You wont be getting ids before initialization. Also `this._Onesignal.getIds()` returns a promise with ids. It does not take a parameter.

```
this._OneSignal.startInit("568ed291-8d30-441f-b7be-d0d99aaca596", '342271570971');
this._OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this._OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);

this._OneSignal.getIds().then(ids => { //here 

        alert(JSON.stringify(ids.userId));

        this.storage.set('playersID',  ids.userId);

});
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I got this error message [ts] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. however, I was getting alert at where the code were before, I think my challenge is the storage not the userId

Comment: no success yet, still the same [ts] Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: did you call the function correctly? `this._OneSignal.getIds().then((ids)`?

Comment: Also which storage are you using?

Comment: cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160408/discussion-between-laidelawal-and-suraj-rao).

Comment: @Ionic/storage?